# Triangle Transformation that keeps the area at 1. Triangle distribution

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a probability distribution whose CDF with the upper bound has to be 1(like usual). The distribution is a triangle. The basic distribution is trivially like this:

$f(x)=2-2x$

$F(x)=2x-x^2$

A plausible condition on the upper bound must be

$uf(u)*.5=1$

$f(u)=\frac{2}{u}$

In essence I want a PDF and CDF for every conceivable triangle(degenerates for higher values) whose area is 1. To be clear, I don't really need fancy triangles, just a simple degenerate triangle. Hopefully with just one parameter but its possible it might require two parameters. The PDF and CDF above have to be a special case of this distribution.

edit:

Here is my attempt to answer this question, it is clearly wrong but I don't know why.

The general linear form is:

$f(x)=a-bx$

The area underneath the triangle must be 1.

$\int^u_0f(x)dx=1$

The following confirms the base*height formula above. The line should intercept the x-axis at the upper bound.

$f(u)=0$

Finally, the top of the triangle is found when $x=0$:

$f(0)=a$

Combining these conditions yields:

$b=\frac{2}{u^2}$

$a = \frac{2}{u}$

$f(x)=\frac{2x}{u}(u-1)$

Which is does not seem to behave the way I want it to.

Comment: The pdf of what is currently called a triangular dist. should be $f(x)=1-|x|$ for $-1<x<1$, whereas $f(x)=2-2x$ is a pdf is you specify $0<x<1$. The area under it has the shape of a right triangle, not an isoceles triangle...

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for your comment. The PDF I specified was just an example. In my update, I give the more general linear form. I think the absolute value you put forth doesn't give rise to more than one distribution.

Comment: Ah, you mean the pdf has the shape of a right triangle with the axes, thus is for positive values of $x$ only ? In this case, the general form is $f(x)=-\tfrac{b^2}{2}x+b$ for any positive $b$. Besides, what do you call a *degenerate* triangle ?

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry i'm kind of slow. Yes I think it works only for positive values of x. Right angle... why? I mean its just a downard sloping line from the y axis. The only right angle I see is the x and y line intersection? Technically it is part of the triangle. Degenerate triangle just means that y is strictly decreasing in x. My formula restricts the upper intersection, and your formula restricts the upper bound. I thin they both work?

Comment: Wait maybe you aren't restricting the upper bound... but the area doesn't seem to add up to 1?

Comment: Yes, I do not restrict the upper bound. Any upper bound is good (why should it be fixed to 2 ?) as long as the slope is steep enough to have final area under the curve = 1...

Comment: @JeanMarie Somehow if I integrate your function from 0 to u. I still get the same a as before, so the result is the same as the one below. Maybe there is a reason for the restriction?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the general form just posting it here to close the thread. The procedure I followed is as described above, it just turns out I had an error. The distribution of all degenerate triangles is the following.

$f(x)=\frac{2}{u^2}(u-x)$

Where u is where the triangle intersects the x axis.

Comment: It would mean that, always, $f(0)=2$. This looks restrictive ! See my other comment.

Comment: Corrected it, I think it's good now?